# How to remove readiness and liveness check in the entire cluster

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-operator

I'm using a K8S operator that has some initial delay in setting up deployments due to a high hardcoded value for the `initialDelaySeconds`. This is a bug in that K8S operator. I cannot change the operator code to decrease this time but is there a workaround like disabling health and readiness check in the entire K8S cluster?

Comment: How are you deploying this K8s Operator? Is it via Helm, then they might have exposed a variable to disable it. If you really want to go deep into this, you might design your own mutating admission webhook that could remove it.

Comment: Via Helm, I asked the maintainers and check myself, unfortunately, they haven't exposed it. Could you elaborate a bit more on your solution?